# What are the best parameters for λCDM?

Tags: cosmology

A man with one watch knows what time it is. A man with two watches is never sure. I've seen several combinations of 'standard' λCDM parameters. The NED search site has the three year WMAP as the default and you can select the 5 year as an option. I've seen several papers on the Plank study with a different set than the WMAP. Is there a set of parameters that everyone agrees are the best use as of 2015?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wikipedia has a specific [section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model#Parameters) on it in its lambda-cdm model entry. It cites a [publicly available peer reviewed paper](http://xxx.lanl.gov/pdf/1502.01589v2.pdf) published by ESO in 2015.

Comment: Even the go-to reference that is the Planck results can be a bit difficult to navigate, though. Do you use the Planck only results? The Planck+BAO constraints? The Planck+lensing? Planck+lensing+BAO? I usually use the last column of Table 4 (from the paper). I think this is the same as on Wikipedia.

Comment: I'd like to think science is more objective than just arbitrarily picking the last column in a group of 6.  In addition, the Sullivan document that was based mainly on SNe Ia reports an H0 of 73, which is considerably higher than the 67 in the 2015 Plank document.  Do we go with cosmic parameters based on CMB or SNe Ia?